# C# Asp .net Identity Add Current User to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to do a create on a simple model for a test. I can't figure out how to attach the user to the model being submitted. I tried several different methods from over posts but couldn't seem to get the model to submit.

```
public class StockController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public StockController() 
    {

    }

    // GET: Stock
    [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userStocks = db.Stocks.Where(p => p.User.Id == currentUserId);
        //var test1 = userStocks.ToList();
        return View(userStocks.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Stock/Details/5
    [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Stock stock = db.Stocks.Find(id);
        if (stock == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(stock);
    }

    // GET: Stock/Create
    [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Stock/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StockId,Name,Ticker")] Stock stock)
    {
        //var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //var user = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
           // var user = db.Users.Select(p => p.UserName == User.Identity.GetUserName()).FirstOrDefault();
            stock.User = user;
            db.Stocks.Add(stock);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(stock);
    }
```

here is the model for the user, and the stock

```
public class Stock
{
    public int StockId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set;}

}
```

and the Application User Model

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User manager uses different `ApplicationDbContext` object instance than your controller. Therefor EF could not trace user object properly. To workaround simply alter your `Stock` class like this:

```
public class Stock
{
    // other members here

    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Now change post back Create action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StockId,Name,Ticker")] Stock stock)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        stock.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Stocks.Add(stock);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(stock);
}
```